# Geometry - Tangent circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

[image]

Let chords AC and BD of a circle ω intersect at P. A smaller circle ω1 is tangent to ω at T and
to segments AP and DP at E and F respectively.

(a) Prove that ray T E bisects arc ABC of ω.

(b) Let I be the incenter of triangle ACD and M be the midpoint of arc ABC of ω. Prove that
MA = MI = MC.

(c) Let F* be the common point of ω1 and line EI other than E. Prove that I, F0
, D, T are
concyclic.

(d) Prove that DF*
is tangent to ω1. This means that F = F*
, so that E, F, I are collinear

I have proved a, b and c so may assume that these are true. I need help in proving that d is true.

Comment: Can you provide a drawing ?

Comment: One is now provided

Comment: You can zoom in on the picture so see the letters, ill work on making them bigger in the meantime

Comment: @Narasimham I have uploaded another image

Comment: Missing $B$ and $P$

Comment: That is because the diagram was constructed for part d only, therefore we do not know where B or P are. You can construct them if you think they will help

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First of all, from previous parts, $\beta = \beta_1 = ... = \beta_6$.

Following part of the given solution, $\triangle MAE \sim \triangle MTA$. This leads to $\dfrac {MA}{MT} = \dfrac {EM}{AM}$. This further means $\dfrac {MI}{MT} = \dfrac {ME}{MI}$ (from part (a)). The newly formed ratio, together with the common angle $\tau$ give $\triangle MEI \sim \triangle MIT$. This further means $\lambda = \lambda_1$.

$\angle 1 = \tau + \lambda = \tau + \lambda_1 = \angle 2 = \angle 3$. Result follows from the converse of angle in alternate segment.

Comment: Are you sure PF'I is the exterior angle to the correct cyclic quadrilateral? Which cyclic are you referring to? As far as I can tell, PF'I is exterior to IF'DT, not IF'TN

Comment: @KingJ  You are right. Got temporarily distracted by the complicated diagram. Will have it deleted shortly.

Comment: @KingJ Post **completely re-written**. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have since found.

MCE = MAC = MTA

therefore MAE is similar to MTA

so we have ME*MT=MA^2

we also know MA=MI

so, MI^2 - ME*MT

now, MEI is similar to MTI

Angle chasing from here yeilds,

MEI = MIT = MIE +EIT = F'ID + F'DT = F'ID + F'TI + IF'T

Note also that,

MEC = AET = EF'T = IF'T

and

MEI = MEC + CEF'

Adding these together gives us

CEF' = F'ID + F'TI = F'ID + F'DI

Let DF' meet AC at P

Looking at PEF' we see that PF'E = F'DI + F'ID = PEF'

therefore PEF' is isosceles with PE = PF'

Therefore PF' is a tangent